# validationOptions not working with custom bindingHandlers

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm using durandal/breeze with Knockout.

I am working on validation on my inputs with `ko.validation`.

Here is a classic:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myDate, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error'}" />

.input-validation-error {
    background-color: #c75b55 !important;
}
```

This one works pretty well: when validation failed, the input textbox is marked in red.

Now I would like to use a bindingHandlers in place of a 'simple' `value` binding:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="dateRW: myDate, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error'}" />

ko.bindingHandlers.dateRW = {
    //dateRW --> the 'read-write' version used both for displaying & updating dates
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();            
        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var value = $(element).val();
            var dateFormatted = moment.utc(value, "DD/MM/YYYY");
            //if (dateFormatted.isValid())
            if (dateFormatted)
                observable(dateFormatted.toDate())
            else 
                observable(null);
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var date = (typeof value !== 'undefined') ? moment.utc(value) : null;
        var dateFormatted = (date != null) ? date.format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
        $(element).val(dateFormatted);            
    }
};
```

With this implementation, validation works, I mean `ko.validation.group` is working well

```
var validationErrorsCount = ko.computed(function() {
    if (typeof itinerary() == 'undefined') return;
    var validationErrors = ko.validation.group(itinerary());
    return validationErrors().length;
});
```

But the input textbox is no more marked in red. It seems that 'validationOptions' only work with the value binding.

Any way to have my validation work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The validation framework have hooks for the value binding, you need to call

```
ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("dateRW");
```

edit: its not undefined
https://jsfiddle.net/it3xl/n7aqjor9/

Comment: Are you sure you don't misspelled ? I got the error `Object #<Object> has no method 'makeBindingHandlerValidatable'`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Its a pretty new api function, are you using latest version from https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: Anders, I past my fiddle in your message. Sorry. If your have a time, correct yours http://jsfiddle.net/BSh6X/ and past it back.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `knockout-validation.js` source it calls:

`makeBindingHandlerValidatable('value')` to make the `value` binding automatically validatable.

You could try adding a call to `makeBindingHandlerValidatable` to register your handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dateRW = {
    //dateRW --> the 'read-write' version used both for displaying & updating dates
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
       ...
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
       ...
    }
};

ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable('dataRW');
```

Answer (score 0):

## [validationMessage](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings) binding with an empty element.

I don't wanna have the textbox marked in red.
Sometimes it's allowable to use an additional empty markup (span) with the **validationMessage** binding.

```
<input data-bind="datepickerCustom: myDate"/>
<span data-bind="validationMessage: myDate" class="validationMessage"></span>
```