# Knockout validation not firing with knockout custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a knockout custom binding handler for an input that I need to have validated by knockout-validation.  However nothing I've done has worked.  Validation is not fired.  I *can* get validation firing on a plain ko value binding on an input bound to the same viewmodel property.

What I've found from my research (ko docs, ko-validation github docs and this SO question [validationOptions not working with custom bindingHandlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275700/validationoptions-not-working-with-custom-bindinghandlers/16276462#16276462)
amongst many others) is that you need:

```
ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("yourcustombindinghandlername");
```

to make KO-validation take notice of your custom binding handler.  I have that and I'm still getting no joy.

I've tried debugging through knockout-validation.js for both the value binding and custom binding to see what's happening differently but I can't work out what the entry point for the custom binding validation would be.  My js isn't that strong TBH.

Here's a very simplified version of the code:

HTML:

```
<div>
<div id="vehicleQuoteDetails">
    <div>            
        <div>
            <!--with custom binding-->
            <input data-bind="vehiclemileage: quote.mileage, fieldName: 'mileage'" type="text" id="quoteMileage">
            <!--without custom binding-->
            <input data-bind="value:quote.mileage" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS:

Custom Binding Handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.vehiclemileage = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).on("blur", function (evt) {
            if (evt.timeStamp !== undefined) {
                var fieldName = allBindingsAccessor().fieldName;
                bindingContext.$root.update[fieldName]($(element).val());

            }
            //return true;
        });
        //return true;
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(value);
        //return true;
    }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
function JobQuoteViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.quote = {};

    self.getQuote = function () {

        self.quoteMapping = {
            "mileage": {
                create: function (options) {
                    return ko.observable(options.data).extend({ required: true });
                }
            }
        }

                var quoteResult = { mileage:1234 }

        ko.validation.init();
        ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("vehiclemileage");
        self.quote = ko.mapping.fromJS(quoteResult, self.quoteMapping);
        ko.applyBindings(self);

        //$.ajax({
        //    url: "webapplication6/Home/GetQuote",
        //    type: "GET",
        //    dataType: "JSON",
        //    success: function (result) {
        //        ko.validation.init();
        //        ko.validation.makeBindingHandlerValidatable("vehiclemileage");
        //        self.quote = ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data, self.quoteMapping);
        //        ko.applyBindings(self);
        //    }
        //});
    };

    self.update = {
        mileage: function (value) {

            alert('mileage: ' + value);
        }
    }
    self.getQuote();
}
```

View model instantiation:

```
var jobQuoteVM = new JobQuoteViewModel();
```

And here's the fiddle for the above :https://jsfiddle.net/stevedavey/1j6vphya/

In the example I've got two inputs: one bound to a custom binding handler and one to a simple value binding. The latter is to demonstrate the validation on the plain value binding works fine.

The input on the left is the one bound to a custom binding handler and the input on the right is the value binding.

TIA for any help.

Comment: If there's something about the question that needs improving can someone let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't properly update the observable. You could for example use a simple computed to do so:

https://jsfiddle.net/otjg2L8z/2/

I've slightly amended your custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.vehiclemileage = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var formattedValue = ko.pureComputed({
            read: function () {
                var text = valueAccessor()();
                return text;
            },
            write: function (newValue) {
                valueAccessor()(newValue);
            }
        });
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "blur", function (evt) {
            var modelValue = valueAccessor(),
                elementValue = $(element).val();
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modelValue)) {
                formattedValue(elementValue);
            }    

            if (evt.timeStamp !== undefined) {
                var fieldName = allBindingsAccessor().fieldName;
                bindingContext.$root.update[fieldName]($(element).val());

            }
        });

        //return true;
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,     viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        $(element).val(value);
        //return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  Just to check I'm getting this correctly: Ko-validation needs the custom binding handler to do what the ko binding handler (e.g. a value binding) would normally do to be able detect the change and thus validate it.  In this case we need to update the observable on blur (value bindings updating the observable on loss of focus).  Thanks, your answer has clarified my understanding of KO as well as giving me a solution.  Cheers!

Comment: yes, you were updating the value of the input, but not the observable itself.

Comment: Thank you for the help and validating my understanding.