# Using date picker with knockout and knockout validation framework

Tags: javascript, validation, date, knockout.js, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I'm using the https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ date picker with knockout, and using the knockout validation framework's ISODate validation.

What I am finding with the date picker is that, if an invalid date is entered with the keyboard (keepInvalid: true) a dp.error event is raised by the picker. If I then correct the date with the keyboard the picker is not raising the dp.change event. Is this expected and correct behaviour by the picker? If so, is there a workaround that I can use to address the concerns of my users, as described below?

When using the date picker the ISODate validation will never fire. But I wish to have the picker NOT automatically correct something that the user types into the text box. What I need to have happen instead is for the underlying observable to be updated with the invalid entry, and then let the knockout validation fire, which will update the UI with the error validation state.

I'm getting complaints about the automatic correction of invalid dates entered with the keyboard, because there is no notification that the date value has been silently changed.

So I am using the picker with the option keepInvalid: true. The binding handler updates the observable in the dp.change event. I've updated the suggested binding handler to also update the observable in the dp.error event.

This *almost* does what I need. But when I do the following:

1. Select todays date with the picker, leading to '2016-04-22' being put in the text box (and observable).
2. Use the keyboard to insert an invalid character so we have '2016-0a4-22' in the text box (and observable). The knockout validation fires which is the desired behaviour.
3. Now correct the date with the keyboard by removing the invalid character, putting the text box back to '2016-04-22'. The knockout validation is not cleared. This is because the 'dp.change' event is not being fired when the text box is updated to remove the incorrect value. At this point the text box has '2016-04-22' but the underlying observable still has the invalid '2016-0a4-22'

If I were to correct the date using the picker rather than the keyboard then the dp.change event is fired and the validation error state goes away. But not if I correct things using the keyboard.

Comment: Heya. Welcome to (asking at) Stack Overflow. Your post makes a lot of sense, but I highly recommend you edit it and add a [mcve] and explain what the addition/change is you're aiming for and/or have tried. It would also help if you summarize with a concrete question.

Comment: Seems that you need a custom binding that will apply blur event, which will re-apply the value to the valueAccessor. I've just helped with similar scenario, maybe that helps you in any way.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747210/knockout-validation-not-firing-with-knockout-custom-binding

Comment: I've attempted to trap the 'change' event on the text box within the binding handler, but that event is never firing. My assumption is that it's being eaten by the date picker. I'll try that approach again using 'blur'. Thanks